# logrotate deletes all maillogs older than one day

Tags: log-files, logrotate

I see only two files `maillog` and `maillog.1` in `/var/log`.

`grepping` for maillog in `logrotate.d` directory gives three files that have a mention of `maillog`.

syslog

```
/var/log/messages /var/log/secure /var/log/maillog /var/log/spooler /var/log/boot.log /var/log/cron {
#/var/log/messages /var/log/secure /var/log/spooler /var/log/boot.log /var/log/cron {
        daily
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

syslog-ng

```
/var/log/messages /var/log/secure /var/log/maillog /var/log/spooler /var/log/boot.log /var/log/cron /var/log/kern.log /var/log/kern {
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

and maillog.

```
/var/log/maillog  {
    daily
    compress
#    rotate 365
    rotate 14 
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

I am new to `logrotate` so may be I am missing something obvious. What can be the issue? The setup was already done when I started managing the server so I don't also know as do why do I have 3 mentions for maillog in logrotate.

Comment: Can you also post your default logrotate configuration /etc/logrotate.conf?

Comment: @panaroik Please find the defaults here http://sprunge.us/CQFF

Answer (score 0):

- The first one is created by default.
- The second one is created when installing `syslog-ng`.
- The previous sysadmin creates the third one manually (maybe).

Which syslog service are you running?

```
ps -ef | grep syslog
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since you're using `syslog-ng`, all of the `postrotate` scripts are wrong, change it to something like this:

```
postrotate
    /bin/kill -HUP `cat /opt/syslog-ng/var/run/syslog-ng.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
endscript
```

then run in debug mode (no changes will be made to the logs) to see what happens:

```
logrotate -d -f /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng
```

Comment: `/opt/syslog-ng/sbin/syslog-ng --no-caps`. So, why are logs only 1 day old wven though I have set `rotate 14` in `maillog`.

Comment: `ls -l /var/log/maillog.1`?

Comment: http://sprunge.us/IfDY. I even removed the duplicate logs and still the problem persists.

Comment: Which part did you remove? updated my answer.